# Remove content padding from Vuetify Parallax

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

How to remove padding from the content inside of a Vuetify Parallax?

```
<v-parallax src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/23/22/36/vegetables-2338824_960_720.jpg" style="min-height: 650px">
<v-row
  no-gutters
  align="center"
  justify="center"
  style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)"
>
</v-row>
```

https://codepen.io/mckraemer/full/eYORoBe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Vuetify has not exposed some prop which you need, you can also do that overriding the CSS. In your case, you can put a style tag at the end of the HTML section just like below

```
<style>
  .v-parallax__content {
    padding: 0px !important;
  }
</style>
```

it's working on your codepen

Answer (score 0):

Just be careful, overriding the style .v-parralax_content only works if the  tag is not scoped i.e.

A workaround for this is to create a global css file and override it there. Remember to point to it in your nuxt.config.js, for example:

```
    css: [
  '~/css/main.css'
    ],
```